# What feats can I use to get a companion of any sort?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, familiars

Basically, what feats can I use to get a Cohort, Animal Companion, Familiar, or something similar?  Standard Class Features and ACF's not so much since they're very class specific, but if there are any noteworthy ones (particularly ones you get at low levels) feel free to list them as well.  I know of several but the only one I know that will get me the critter I want is Leadership, and that is being left to RP.  Of great interest are ways to earn this companion that wouldn't sound like Leadership.

Note: In a previous build idea the DM objected to Dragon Cohort, but soon after decided to let me take it but I'd have to RP getting the cohort in-game.  It was a rather tentative ruling, and I'm not sure if something similar will happen again, but suggest away regardless.

Note2: I don't know if it matters, but we are allowed Pathfinder stuff for the most part, from what I can tell at least.  So if there's something in PF that would prove relevant to this toss it in.

Comment: I believe some of these options are class-specific, or at least specific to a certain type of class. What are you playing as?

Comment: This question is in regards to a Factotum build, but I may dip into other classes, not sure.  Many of the feats out there can be taken by other classes so long as they somehow meet the requirements too, hence asking this question.  I'm mostly looking for feats, but significantly useful/low level class features are of interest as well.

Comment: What critter did you want?

Comment: A Beguiler from Shining South.  I am interested in means of getting companions that don't let me get it though, because if I can't get it I'd still like to get something.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Feats Granting Companions, Cohorts, Familiars, and Mounts

- The feat **Apprentice** (*Dungeon Master's Guide 2* 176) explicitly allows the creature to call on his mentor for aid.
- The feat **Dragon Cohort** (*Draconomicon* 104) grants the creature a dragon cohort.
- The feat **Dragon Steed** (*Draconomicon* 105) grants the creature a dragonnel that serves "much like a cohort."
- The feat **Extra Familiar** (*Dragon* #280 62) grants the creature an additional familiar. *Note:* Published *way* early in the *Dungeons and Dragons, 3rd Edition* life cycle, this feat's absent prerequisites and written assuming the creature already *has* a familiar. Talk to the DM.
- The feat [**Leadership**](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#leadership) (*PH* 97, *DMG* 106-7) grants the creature a cohort.
- The feat **Mentor** (*Dungeon Master's Guide 2* 176) grants the creature an apprentice.
- The feat **Obtain Familiar** (*Complete Arcane* 81) grants the creature a familiar.
- The feat **Shadow Familiar** (*Tome of Magic* 138) grants the creature a familiar with the template dark (*Tome of Magic* 161).
- The feat **Touch of Hate** (*Player's Guide to Faerûn* 177), once every 10 days, grants the creature the ability as a standard action to touch an animal and, if it fails the saving throw, transform the animal and gain permanent control of it.
- The feat **Undead Leadership** (*Libris Mortis* 31) grants the creature undead followers and, optionally, an undead cohort.
- The feat **Wild Cohort** (Random Encounters column ["Wild Life"](https://web.archive.org/web/20210217062407/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/re/20031118a)) grants the creature a lesser version of the druid's animal companion.

---

**The Beguiler**
According to page 61 of *Shining South*, "A beguiler can be acquired as a familiar by a 7th-level arcane caster with the Improved Familiar feat." The feat Improved Familiar is on *DMG* 200.

Comment: Thankyou, this is exactly what I was looking for all around.  Everyone's answers were good, but this not only answered the general question but also the specific reason for the question.  One question though, I'm not familiar with the acronym PG.  I believe LM is Libris Mortis but if it isn't please correct me.

Comment: PG is the Player's Guide to Fâerun. A bit unclear, yes. And LM is indeed the Libris Mortis.

Comment: You could also just buy a dog, which has the upside of not requiring any resources other than gold for the purchase, some meat, and maybe a chew toy.

Comment: @GMJoe Hey, hey! Get you and your "practical" and "convenient" suggestions out of here! This is a question about *feats*. Yeesh. `:-)`

Comment: Is there a reason you list the beguiler as a separate entry? My impression is that the text you quote is meant to add the beguiler to the list of familiars one can take with Improved Familiar, which already requires being able to have a familiar in the first place.

Comment: @Zachiel It's mentioned in the question's comments.

Comment: I see. Maybe we should edit that into the question...

Answer (score 1):

The first that comes to mind for me is [Wild Cohort](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/re/20031118a), which works just like Animal Companion for the Druid except you treat yourself as being three levels lower. For a magical approach I'd say Obtain Familiar (CA, p.81), though this require you to have Knowledge (Arcana) 4 and to *be* a 3rd level Arcane Caster. Since nowhere is written what an Arcane Caster *is*, you should run this by your DM first. If they agree with an Arcane caster being someone who can cast Arcane spells, you should be good.

In case of the Beguiler you could try [turning them into a PC race then recruit them as a cohort](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=7928.0), but again you should ask your DM.

Or if it is an animal, you could always try Handle Animal to train it. As a Factotum this should not be much of a problem.

Comment: Wild Cohort looks pretty decent, and I'm pretty sure I'd be able to go with the Obtain Familiar.  Both are useful in their own right, and while I am looking for these options in general too neither of these allow me to get the obscure critter I *really* want.  Still adding Wild Cohort to my reference list though.

Comment: Can't edit above comment so I have to use another.  Beguilers are already allowed as a cohort as per the book's stat entry apparently.  The problem is the only way to get a cohort I know of is the Leadership feat which isn't allowed.

Comment: I forgot the obvious one, added now. And I'm not sure if you could perchance just buy one as one would buy an animal/mount.

Answer (score 1):

#### Improved Familiar (and other familiars)

You know about Obtain Familiar already, as you mentioned it. But it's got a fairly restrictive list of options. [Improved Familiar](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#improvedFamiliar) lets you take a wider list of options. The important part is at the end of the feat (emphasis mine):

> The list in Table: Improved Familiar by Alignment presents only a few
> possible improved familiars. ***Almost any creature of the same general
> size and power as those on the list makes a suitable familiar***. Nor is
> the master’s alignment the only possible categorization. For instance,
> improved familiars could be assigned by the master’s creature type or
> subtype, as shown in Table: Improved Familiar by Type/Subtype.

That means the actual list of what you can have is limited to "ask your DM", and can be really large. The Shining South Beguiler should be usable here, as it's no stronger than something already on the list (like [Imp](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/devil.htm#imp)).

There's also other familiar options, but they don't help with your specific creature. I've included them for reference.

Celestial Familiar (Book of Exalted Deeds) adds some extra Celestial creatures as options.

Planar Familiar (Planar Handbook) adds some Outsiders.

Dragon Familiar (Draconomicon) adds Wyrmling Dragons.